# How do you do the last step when converting a CFG to a CNF?

Tags: context-free-grammar, chomsky-normal-form

Given:

```
    S->AcA|BcB
    A->ccBc|ABA|cc
    B->c

step1

    S0->S
    S->AcA|BcB
    A->ccBc|ABA|cc
    B->c


step2             // change symbol to terminals?

    S0->S
    S->ABA|BBB
    A->BBBB|ABA|BB
    B->c

step3             // split?

    S0->S
    S->ABA
    S->BBB
    A->BBBB
    A->ABA
    A->BB
    B->c

step4             // what to do when A->AXA?

    S0->S
    S->ABA
    S->BBB
    A->BBBB   //??
    A->ABA    //??
    A->BB     //??
    B->c
```

I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: I fixed what appears to be an oversight in the code formatting. I also fixed the erroneous tag; `cnf` means something different from Chomsky Normal Form here, as you can tell from the excerpt shown by hovering over the tag or when you type it in. Finally, I rewrote the title to be at least a little clearer, but it still needs to be a lot more specific. What part exactly are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: @NathanTuggy He says in the code comments "What do you do when A -> AXA?". It was clear to me what he needed once I refreshed my knowledge of CNF.

Comment: @MillieSmith: Well, tbh my knowledge of CNF is limited to the name and a vague idea that formal grammar specifications exist, so I did as much as I could. If you can rewrite the title again to make it specific, that would be quite helpful for future reference.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I did my best, though I struggled to make it better than what you changed it to haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no step 2 for you. [Step 2 is removing epsilon rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form#Converting_a_grammar_to_Chomsky_Normal_Form), and you have no epsilon rules.

You don't have a step 3 either, because B->c has a terminal - not a nonterminal - on its right hand side. There are no unit rules of the form:

```
Terminal -> Terminal.
```

This leaves us after your step 1:

```
S0 -> S
S -> AcA|BcB
A -> ccBc|ABA|cc
B -> c
```

You need to get the rest of your rules in the form of:

```
X -> YZ //where X,Y,Z are all nonterminals
```

To convert a string of nonterminals and terminals into the above form, you take the first nonterminal or terminal from the front, and then you turn the rest of the string into a new rule, and use that rule on the end. I didn't explain that very well, so let's look at an example.

```
//To convert
S -> AcA
//we split it into A and cA, and define a new rule C -> cA, giving:
S -> AC
C -> cA
//Then, C -> cA needs to be converted to the same form, so just replace c with B
S -> AC
C -> BA
```

However, throw out the above, because first I'm going to just change all the `c`s to B, since that will happen anyway:

```
S0 -> S
S -> ABA|BBB
A -> BBBB|ABA|BB
B -> c
```

Now that I look at your question again, this is where you were at. You'd gone one step further to:

```
S0 -> S
S -> ABA
S -> BBB
A -> BBBB
A -> ABA
A -> BB
B -> c
```

If we take the first S, and use the method described above, we get:

```
S -> ABA
//goes to
S -> AC
C -> BA
```

Doing the rest of the rules, we get:

```
//second S
S -> BD
D -> BB

//first A
A -> DD

//second A:
A -> AC
```

Combining this all, we get:

```
S0 -> S
S -> AC
S -> BD
A -> DD
A -> AC
A -> BB
B -> c
C -> BA
D -> BB
```